# Number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$.

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

Question:

> Find the number of non trivial ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$. ($f$ is not necessarily unitary, i.e., $f(1)$ need not be $1$.)

Suppose $f$ is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$.

Consider $f$ as a additive group homomorphism.  Let $k= |\ker f|$ and 
$ t = |\operatorname{im}(f)|$. Then $k\mid 12$ and $t\mid 24$ and $kt=12$, by first isomorphism 
theorem of groups.

There are two possibilities $k=3$, $t=4$   and $k=6$, $t=2$.

For the first case $f$ should map $1$ to an element of the subgroup generated by $7$ as there is a unique subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{28}$ of order $4$ generated by $7$. For the second case $1$ has to map to $14$, for the same reasoning.

So there are at most two ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$.
Question is how to check the possible maps which are ring homomorphisms.

Thanks.

Comment: What about $k=12$?

Comment: We need non trivial homomorphisms.

Comment: For counting the group homomorphisms, it's true there's only one subgroup of order 4, but you can map 1 to *any* generator of that subgroup.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are right. Thanks

Comment: So why didn't you change your incorrect statement that $f$ should map $1$ to $7$ when you edited the question?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphisms-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n/1564242#1564242

Answer (score 9):

Number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_m$ into $\mathbb Z_n$ is $2^{[w(n)-w(n/\gcd(m,n))]}$ , where $w(n)$ denotes the numbers of prime divisors of positive integer n.
From this formula we get number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$ is $2$.

Comment: Will above formula work for Zn to Zn. Please reply

Comment: What is $w(1)$ defined

Answer (score 6):

Even if not necessarily $f(1)=1$, we still need $f(1)\cdot f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)$, hence $f(1)$ must be a solution of $x^2-x=0$ in $\mathbb Z_{28}$. The solutions for this are the residue classes of: $0, 1, 8, 21$.
Therefore, $f\colon \mathbb Z_{12}\to\mathbb Z_{28}$ is necessarily induced by $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto cx$ with $c\in \{0,1,8,21\}$.
Also, we need $28|12c$, i.e. $c$ must be a multiple of $7$. This leaves only the cases $c=0$ and $c=21$.

Answer (score 3):

A ring homomorphism $f:Z_{12}\to Z_{28}$ must map $1$ to $1$, because ring homomorphisms do that (if you are *not* assuming your ring homomorphisms to be unitary, you should always be explicit about it!)

Now $\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{\text{$12$ summands}}=0$ in $Z_{12}$, so applying $f$ we must have $$\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{\text{$12$ summands}}=\underbrace{f(1)+f(1)+\dots+f(1)}_{\text{$12$ summands}}=0$$ in $Z_{28}$. As this is not true, there is no morphism!

Comment: We assume that f is not unitary.

Comment: Then **please** do add that information to the question.

Comment: You should not have accepted this, as this does not do what you wanted"

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Applying the hom $\rm\,f\,$ to $\rm\:12\cdot 1 = 0\:$ and $\:1^2\!= 1,\:$ denoting $\rm\:e = f(1),\:$ we infer that $\rm\: 12\,e = 0\:\Rightarrow\:28\:|\:12\,e\:\Rightarrow\: 7\:|\:e,\:$ hence $\rm\:mod\ 28\!:\ e \equiv 0,7,14,21;\:$ also $\rm\:e^2 \equiv e\:$ hence $\rm\:e\equiv\,\ldots$

To understand better the role played by idempotents $\rm\:e^2 = e\:$ look up the [Peirce decomposition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_decomposition)