# Finding number of various homomorphisms from cyclic group $C_m$ of order $m$ to $C_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Finding number of various homomorphisms from cyclic group $C_m$ of order $m$ to $C_n$.

Suppose that $C_m=\langle a\rangle$ and $C_n=\langle b\rangle$. A homomorphism $f$ from $C_m$ to $C_n$ is determined completely by $f(a)$. If $f(a)=k\in C_n$, then $f(a^r):=f(a)^r=k^r \pmod n, r=0,1,2,...,m-1$ determines $f$.

$f(a)^m=f(a^m)=f(1)=1\implies |f(a)||m$ and by Lagrange's theorem $|f(a)|$ should divide $n$ as well. So $|f(a)|$ should divide $\gcd (m,n)$.  So total number of the homomorphisms is $\sum_{k|\gcd(m,n)}\phi(k)$, which equals $\gcd (m,n)$.

**Particular cases:**

1. Finding total number of onto homomorphisms

If $n\not| m$, then no onto homomorphism exists (for if it did, then first isomorphism theorem will be violated).

So suppose that $n|m$. To find onto $f$, $f(a)$ must be able to generate $C_n$. That is, $\langle f(a)\rangle=C_n$ and since $C_n$ is cyclic $f(a)$ can have $\phi (n)$ possible values in $C_n$. This way, no. of onto homomorphisms is $\phi(n)$.

2. Finding total number of 1-1 homomorphisms

By First homomorphism theorem, such homomorphism $g$ must have kernal of order 1 and $C_m$ must be isomorphic to $g(C_m)\le C_n$ (so $m|n$) . So $g$ must map generator $a$ to an element of order $m$ in $C_n$.

Total number of elements of order $m$ in $C_n$ is $\phi (m)$ and so total number of the 1-1 homomorphisms is $\phi(m)$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Have you compared for correctness with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372471/all-group-homomorphism-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273169/number-of-homomorphisms-from-bbbz-m-to-bbbz-n)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Thanks for the links. I couldn’t find them earlier. But I also want to say that this question is not a duplicate as it  is about finding no. of onto and 1-1 homomorphisms also whereas the suggested links are about finding the total number of homomorphisms. Please advice on onto and one -one part of this proof. Thanks.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The first part in my post (that is the part before 'particular cases') seems correct to me and I think that is also in line with answer in one of the suggested links in your comment. It's the 'particular cases' part where I request review.

Comment: Use `$a\nmid b$` for $a\nmid b$.