# To find all Ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_m$ to $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: ring-theory

How to find all Ring homomorphisms from  $\mathbb Z_m$ to $\mathbb Z_n$ (with the usual ring structure ) ?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate...

Comment: Note that by the usual definition, all ring homomorphisms map the identity of one ring to the identity of the other.

Comment: See  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphism-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n?rq=1).

Comment: (The weaker requirement of ring homomorphism allows for a more interesting consideration; if you really insist on ring homomorphisms, see the comment by Omnom... above).