# How to find all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12} \to \mathbb Z_{30}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, cyclic-groups

> How to find all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12} \to \mathbb Z_{30}$?

I know that it is enough to determine $f([1]_{12})$ ; moreover $f([1]_{12})$ should be an idempotent element of $\mathbb Z_{30}$ and $\text{ord}(f([1]_{12})\mid 12$ and $30$, so we must find the idempotents in $\mathbb Z_{30}$ whose additive orders divide $\gcd(12,30)=6$. But this still leaves a lot to check. Is there any further restrictions on homomorphisms of such type?

Comment: If you really mean **ring** homomorphisms, I believe one part of the definition is that $f(1)=1$, so in that case there will only be one such homomorphism. If instead what you really mean is a **group** homomorphism only, then $\mathbb Z_{30}$ has unique subgroups of order $6,3,2$ and $1$ respectively. These have $\varphi(6)=2,\varphi(3)=2,\varphi(2)=1$ and $\varphi(1)=1$ generators respectively, and $f$ should map $[1]_{12}$ to a generator. That provides you with six such homomorphisms.

Comment: @String I think there is no *unitary* ringhomomorphisms here at all. In $\mathbb Z_{12}$ we have $12=0$ so it should be mapped to $0$. However, in $\mathbb Z_{30}$ we do not have $12=0$.

Comment: @drhab: Still homomorphisms between cyclic groups map generators to generators and are determined entirely by the image of the *standard generator* $1$ in the pre-image.

Comment: @String Yes, I agree with that. But not with "so in that case there will be only one such homomorphism." I should say: at most one.

Comment: @drhab: Ah, I see. You are absolutely correct!

Comment: [this is mostly duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/263063/29335) but maybe the OP has more specific questions about a particular step in this case.

Comment: the ring homomorphism might not send unity to unity ....

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the OP has thought that there is "*a lot to check*". There are only six possibilities: $f(1)\in\{0,5,10,15,20,25\}$ and among these the idempotents are $\{0,10,15,25\}$, so there are four ring homomorphisms.