# The number of nonzero ring homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_{30}\rightarrow \mathbb Z_{42}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups

I have managed to prove the the number of group homomorphisms is $\mathbb Z_m\rightarrow \mathbb Z_n$ is $\gcd (m,n)$, which is my case is $6$. However, I was told that the number of nonzero (non-unital) ring homomorphisms is $4$. Can someone explain how to reach this conclusion?

Comment: The number of unital ring homomorphisms is either $1$ or $0$ depending on $m$ and $n$, as it is uniquely determined by where it sends $1$, and this must be sent to $1$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry, I meant to write nonunital. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, so the part about being uniquely determined by where it sends $1$ still holds. Now the image must be an idempotent, which should allow you to conclude.

Comment: Your homomorphism must map $1$ to an element $a\in\Bbb{Z}_{42}$ that A) satisfies the equation $30a=0$, AND B) the equation $a^2=a$.

Comment: Also, Chinese Remainder Theorem lets you say that $\mathbb Z_{42}\cong \mathbb Z_6\times\mathbb Z_{7}$.

Comment: Building on Thomas Andrews' hint: The solutions to $a^2=a$ in $\Bbb{Z}_6$ are easy to find. And there are exactly four of them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why not $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_7$? This way can see that there are eight idempotents.

Comment: Because I wanted to emphasis the common $\mathbb Z_6$ in both of them. Specifically, any image of $1$ must be of the form $(a,0)$ for $a\in\mathbb Z_6$. But yes, finding the idemponents in $\mathbb Z_6$ is tantamount to finding the idempotents in $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$. @user26857

Answer (score 5):

**Result:** The number of ring homomorphism from $Z_m$ into $Z_n$ is equal to $2^{\omega(n)-\omega(n/(m,n))}$, where $\omega(a)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $a$.

Given $m=30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ and $n=42=2\cdot3\cdot7$ hence $2^{\omega(42)-\omega(42/(30,42))}=2^2=4.$

Comment: I remember since I was a student a nice AMM article proving that result. (+1)

Comment: Yes I also remember that. It was beautiful so I couldn't resist to mention.

Comment: @user26857 could you perhaps cite the article? Thanks!

Comment: @Exterior The result is easier to prove than find out. Just count the number of elements of the set $\{e\in\mathbb Z_n:e^2=e,me=0\}$.

Comment: I've posted an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1564242/121097) which contains the required reference.