# how many ring homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_{18} \to \mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphisms-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n), ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_m \to \mathbb Z_n$ has been described when $m<n$.

But what happens when $m>n$ ?

Particularly,

> How many ring homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_{18} \to \mathbb{Z}_6$

My thought is that:

there is a basic ring homomorphism: trivial one

Another one is $\phi(1) \to 1$  since $\phi(ab) = ab = \phi(a)\phi(b)$

The last one is $\phi(1) \to 3$. For this case, $\phi(ab) = ab*\phi(1) = 3ab$.

$\phi(a)\phi(b) = 3a*3b = 9ab = 3ab$ because I do "mod 6".

I just noticed $\phi(1) \to 4$ also works.

So there are 4 ring homomorphism. Is my thought correct?

Comment: This question is addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphisms-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n

Comment: Do you demand that a ring homomorphism send the identity of the domain to the identity of the codomain?

Comment: The idea is in the duplicate obvious also work for $m\ge n$. Is there any reason to reopen this post?

Comment: I don't think so @ArcticChar