# Find all homomorphisms of the ring $ \mathbb{Z_6} $ in $ \mathbb{Z_{15}} $ (verification).

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

So this is what I did

Will be homomorphism if and only if the two conditions are satisfied.

n= 6 m= 15 a ={1, 2, ...., 15}

i) an $\equiv$ 0 (mod m)

ii) a $\equiv$ $a^2$ (mod m)

The only two number that satisfies both conditions are 0 and 5.

I also use the formula ( $2^{w(l)-w(\frac{1}{(l,k)})}$ where l=15,k=6) to know how many numbers are homeomorphism and also got two.

Is this correct?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphisms-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n) for the number of ring homomorphisms in general. Sorry, the other one is for group homomorphisms. And yes, the formula is  $2^{\omega(n)-\omega(n/(m,n))}$, where $\omega(a)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $a$. This is indeed $2^{2-1}=2$.

Comment: Is the other part also correct? The homomorphisms are 0 and 5?

Comment: Where do you have a doubt?

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while but I understood what you said, sorry.