# Find all the ring morphisms from $ℤ_{15}$ to $ℤ_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Find all the ring morphisms from $ℤ_{15}$ to $ℤ_3$.

I know the axioms that have to be satisfied in order for a function to be a ring (homo)morphism but I don't know how to go about finding them. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/965497/592024

Comment: There are three morphisms. One where $f(1)=0,f(1)=1,f(1)=2$. The mapping of $1$ fully determines the morphism as $\mathbb Z_{15}$ is cyclic.

Comment: Do ring morphisms map $1$ onto $1$?

Comment: @Bernard One can map every element to 0.

Comment: That's not the usual convention in commutative algebra.

Comment: If ring homomorphisms are supposed to map $1$ into $1$, then there's just one. Please, specify your definition of ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $f([n]_{15}) = [n]_{3} f([1])$.

Comment: sorry, @user458276, I still don't understand.

Comment: As other users have mentioned, it's sufficient to consider what happens when one applies an ring homomorphism $f$ to $[1]$.

Comment: I know, but I don't understand what the statement in your answer is saying. @user458276